# using writeprivateprofilestringw and readprivateprofilestringw in unicode not working

Tags: c, winapi

I try to write a push-pop like program using `Read/WriteprivateprofilestringW` functions and there are problems I don’t think I can see by myself. If you are kind please have a look at my lines and point me so I get it to run correctly.

When I run it with an already created file, the output of writeprivateprofilestringw's section field name is wrong. I think it’s because I’m using LPWSTR data type but nothing I tried solves it.

output:

`[win32 app\Release\fonemeW.dic]
dictsionar=dicţionar`

expected output:

`[dictionar]
dictsionar=dicţionar`

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  push word into dictionary
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void pushWordW(LPWSTR szWord, LPWSTR szFonems){
WCHAR* szDic=(WCHAR)calloc(MAX_PATH, sizeof(WCHAR));
LPWSTR sztemp=L"dictionar";

    wcscpy(szDic, L"fonemeW.txt");
    getDicFile(&szDic);

    WritePrivateProfileStringW(L"dictionar", szFonems, szWord, szDic);
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  pull word from the dictionary as query fonem string
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void pullWordW(TCHAR* szWord[MAX_PATH], LPWSTR szFonems){
WCHAR* szDic=(WCHAR)calloc(MAX_PATH, sizeof(WCHAR));

    wcscpy(szDic, L"fonemeW.dic");
    getDicFile(&szDic);

    GetPrivateProfileStringW(L"dictionar", szFonems, L"", szWord[0], 0, szDic);
    if(wcslen(szWord[0])==0)
        MessageBox(0, "Word not in the dictionar", "titlu popWordW", 0);
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  test the push-pop (from the dictionary) procedures
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void testPP(void){
LPWSTR szWord=L"dictionar";
    szWord[3]=0x0163;
LPWSTR szFonem=L"dictsionar";

    MessageBoxW(0, szWord, L"titlu testPP", 0);
    pushWordW(szWord, szFonem);//push word into dictionar

    wcscpy(szFonem, L"diade-muh");//query dictionar
    pullWordW(&szWord, szFonem);//pop word from dictionary based on fonem transliteration
    MessageBoxW(0, szWord, L"titlu testPP", 0);
}
```

**edit** i editted the declaration of `szWord` and there seems to be no problems anymore.

Comment: You do realize those are legacy functions, not intended for use by programs written later than 1995?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - To be fair, Windows 95 wasn't really all that good until OSR1 which was 1996. :-) @Paul80 - Maybe you could explain what you mean by `Push/Pop like program`.

Comment: What is the definition of getDicFile? You're passing it a pointer to a pointer (szDic), which is a little suspicious.

Comment: Use a third party ini file library

Answer (score 1):

You did not show the implementation for `getDicFile()`, so I can only assume it works correctly (though the code will leak memory if `getDicFile()` returns a pointer to dynamically allocated memory).

I don't see any problem with the implementation of your `pushWordW()` function.  It should not be using a filename as the INI section name.  So this implies that you are actually passing an incorrect/corrupted pointer to the `lpAppName` parameter of `WritePrivateProfileString()`.

However, I do see problems with the implementation of your `pullWordW()` and `testPP()` functions.

1. in `testPP()`, `szWord` initially points to a string literal, which is **read-only**.  Thus, the statement `szWord[3]=0x0163;` should have caused a run-time error trying to write to read-only memory.  So, either change the literal to `L"dicţionar"` so you do not need `szWord[3]=0x0163;` anymore, or else change the declaration of `szWord` to `WCHAR[]` instead of `LPWSTR`, or use `malloc()`, to allocate writable memory that the literal can then be copied into (in the latter case, don't forget to `free()` it when you are done using it).
2. in `testPP()`, `szFonem` initially points to a **read-only** string literal as well.  Thus, the statement `wcscpy(szFonem, L"diade-muh");` should similarly be causing a run-time error trying to write to read-only memory.
3. when `testPP()` calls `pullWordW()`, passing `szWord` using the `&` operator implies that `pullWordW()` is expected to update `szWord` with a new memory address pointing at the data returned by `GetPrivateProfileStringW`().  The problem is, `GetPrivateProfileStringW()` expects a **pre-allocated** buffer of writable memory to store the data into, but the pointer you are actually passing to it is a pointer to the **read-only literal** that `szWord` was initially set to.  Again, it should be causing a run-time error.  But it actually won't, because you are setting the `nSize` parameter of `GetPrivateProfileStringW()` to 0, telling it that there is no space available at the memory address for it to store data into.  So no run-time errror.  But, let's just say for the sake of argument that it could write data.  `pullWordW()` is not updating its `szWord` parameter to point at any new memory address.  And even if it did, who is responsible for allocating that memory, and who is responsible for freeing it?  Your code is not defining those rules anywhere.

The fact that you are not encountering run-time errors that crash your app likely means that memory is being corrupted instead, in which case all bets are off.

Fix your code to use memory correctly.  For example:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  get dictionary filename
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
bool getDicFile(LPWSTR szDic, int nDic){
    // copy whatever your actual dictionary filename is...
    return (wcscpy_s(szDic, nDic, L"fonemeW.dic") == 0);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  push word into dictionary
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void pushWordW(LPWSTR szWord, LPWSTR szFonems){
    WCHAR szDic[MAX_PATH+1];
    if (getDicFile(szDic, MAX_PATH+1)){    
        WritePrivateProfileStringW(L"dictionar", szFonems, szWord, szDic);
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  pull word from the dictionary as query fonem string
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
bool pullWordW(LPWSTR szWord, int nWord, LPWSTR szFonems){
    LPWSTR szDic[MAX_PATH+1];
    if (getDicFile(szDic, MAX_PATH+1)){
        return (GetPrivateProfileStringW(L"dictionar", szFonems, L"", szWord, nWord, szDic) > 0);
    }
    return false;
}    

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  test the push-pop (from the dictionary) procedures
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void testPP(void){
    WCHAR szWord[256] = L"dictionar";
    szWord[3]=0x0163;
    WCHAR szFonem[12] = L"dictsionar";

    MessageBoxW(0, szWord, L"titlu testPP", 0);
    pushWordW(szWord, szFonem);//push word into dictionar

    wcscpy_s(szFonem, 12, L"diade-muh");//query dictionar
    if (pullWordW(szWord, 256, szFonem)){//pop word from dictionary based on fonem transliteration
        MessageBoxW(0, szWord, L"titlu testPP", 0);
    } else {
        MessageBoxW(0, L"Word not in the dictionar", L"titlu popWordW", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: A string **literal** usually exists in the executable's **read-only** data segment.

Comment: Literals are non-modifiable according to the language specification. I suggest that you listen to Remy who really does know what he is talking about.

Comment: it exist as read-only, to be loaded in memory and then blahblah

Comment: You must be compiling your C code with a compiler option that enables writable literals.  Bad idea, but possible, depending on which compiler you are actually using. See [Why are C string literals read-only?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/294748/) and [comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 1.32](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html).

Comment: so it does work. now u can make a copy and enjoy it by yourself:)

Comment: what c-compiler r u using that is not able to compile it (as to make it run), Remy Lebeau?

Comment: as obs: pls note we don't speak the same language: a *string literal* is not the same as a *literal string*. (a string literal at its best means an address of a string)

Comment: I never said the code could not *compile*. I said the code should be *crashing* when it is run. As David said, string literals are defined to be non-modifiable.  Writing to the memory of a literal should cause a runtime fault, unless you tell the compiler to store literals in writable memory.

Comment: no u r right. we speak the same language. \n *to make it run* pls read make it work; so what c-compilers r out there u're using?

Comment: nevermind the compiler, let's talk about the downvotes. it's a perfect question, so why your vote ?...